# how can I get array back from function to main? I tried below program and got error as error: assignment to expression with array type

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I am trying to get back multiplied matrix array from pointer function to `main`.
I am getting error as timeout: the monitored command dumped core. how to get any array return from function to main?

Here is the code:

```
/* multiplication of matrix in function and printing it in main */
#include <stdio.h>

int pointer(int *, int *); /* function to multiply two matrices */

int main() {
    int i, j, *a;
    int ar2[3][3];
    int ar[3][3] = {
        1, 1, 3,
        2, 1, 8,
        3, 8, 1         
    };
    int ar1[3][3] = {
        1, 1, 3,
        2, 1, 8,
        3, 8, 1          
    };
    a = pointer(ar, ar1);
    printf("asas");
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            printf("%d   ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }            
}

int pointer(int *l, int *k) {
    int i, j, a, m = 0, *n;
    int ar[3][3];
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            for (a = 0; a <= 2; a++) {
                m += *(l + a * 3 + j) * (*(k + a + i * 3));
            }
            ar[i][j] = m;
            m = 0;
        }
    }
    n = ar;
    return (n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ar` is allocated on function stack. When you return from the function it is already gone and it is does not exist in the main.

There are several basic ways to handle it

1. you can make the array in the function static: `static int ar[3][3];`. This will make the array persistent, but every time you call the function, the same array will be changed. So, you cannot have multiple independent pointers. All will point to the same source.
2. you can allocate array dynamically: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int [3][3]))`. Now you have to makes sure that you free it in main after use. This will create independent copies of the array every time you call the function.
3. you can allocate the array in the 'main' and pass a pointer to it to the function in order to assign values: `int main(){int arr[3][3]; pointer(arr,...);} int * pointer(int *arr, ...)...`
4. you can declare your array in the global scope, visible from both, main and pointer. This is similar to #1
   ...

Comment: Solution 3. should be documented as 1. especially considering the array `ar2` is defined in `main` for exactly this approach. solution 1. is bad practice with many drawbacks beyond the OP's skill level, solution 4 too.

Comment: @chqrlie #3 is really different from #1.  #4 is more or less similar to #1.

Comment: What I mean is you should change the order in which you promote solutions: passing the destination array as an extra argument is the most appropriate solution given the rest of the OP's code. I agree that 1. and 4. are basically similar, but bad advice to a beginner in both cases. Solution 3 is fine but requires special handling at the call site.

Comment: I do not promote solutions in any order, I only listed *some* of the most common possibilities. The numbering is arbitrary. It is up to the programmer which solution to use in a particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

`ar` is a local object in the `pointer` function, returning its address to the caller will invoke undefined behavior when the caller accesses it as the contents are no longer in scope and may be used for other purposes.

The array `ar2` is defined in `main()` to receive the result and should be passed to `pointer()` for this purpose.

Note also that your inner loop performs the multiplication in the wrong order: matrix multiplication is not commutative, you compute `k * l` instead of `l * k`, and you would get incorrect output if the matrices in `main` were different.

The inner sum should be `m += l[i][a] * k[a][j]` instead of `m += l[a][j] * k[i][a]`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void pointer(int *ar, const int *l, const int *k) {
    int i, j, a;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int m = 0;
            for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                m += l[i * 3 + a] * k[a * 3 + j];
            }
            *ar++ = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that you are passing the 2D arrays to a function expecting simple pointers to `int`. You should pass the address of the first matrix elements:

```
int main() {
    int ar[3][3] = {
        1, 1, 3,
        2, 1, 8,
        3, 8, 1         
    };
    int ar1[3][3] = {
        1, 1, 3,
        2, 1, 8,
        3, 8, 1          
    };
    int ar2[3][3];
    int i, j;

    pointer(&ar2[0][0], &ar[0][0], &ar1[0][0]);
    printf("asas");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d   ", ar2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;            
}
```

Computing the cell address by hand in the `pointer` function is useful for learning purposes or if the matrix dimensions are unknown at compile time and the compiler does not support C99 variable length arrays. For your purpose, using the proper types in the multiplication function is much simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void multiply(int ar[][3], const int l[][3], const int k[][3]) {
    int i, j, a;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int m = 0;
            for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                m += l[i][a] * k[a][j];
            }
            ar[i][j] = m;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int ar[3][3] = {
        1, 1, 3,
        2, 1, 8,
        3, 8, 1         
    };
    int ar1[3][3] = {
        1, 1, 3,
        2, 1, 8,
        3, 8, 1          
    };
    int ar2[3][3];
    int i, j;

    multiply(ar2, ar, ar1);
    printf("asas");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d   ", ar2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;            
}
```

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. many concept more clear now. thank for entertaining beginner amateur question

Comment: i was practicing different ways to perform same operation using pointers. now i am more confident coding pointer